# Case-dependent indent

Tags: floats, captions, indentation

I want to have an indent at figure captions but not at table captions. I already read the caption documentation but did not find an optional argument to just set this indent for figures. A web search wasn't successful, too. I add a MWE below. Thanks for your help!

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newlength\myindention

\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{figure}{\hspace*{\myindention}{#1} {#2}}
\setlength\myindention{\parindent}


\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont={sl}, textfont={small}, format=plain, labelsep=period, justification=justified, aboveskip=0.5em, belowskip=0.3cm}

\captionsetup[table]{labelfont={normal}, textfont={small, sl}, format=plain, labelsep=newline, justification=raggedright, singlelinecheck=false, aboveskip=0.5em, belowskip=0.3cm}

\captionsetup{labelformat=figure}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{figure}
\caption{This is a figure caption with a long text to show the indent which is defined by a parindent in front of the figure label}
\end{figure}%I want to have the indent in front of the label here
\begin{table}
\caption{This is a table caption}%The indent should be deleted here in front of the label
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT**

At the moment it looks like this:

[image]

But I want the indent in front of "Tabelle" to be removed:

[image]

Comment: You can't obtain it this way: captions are centred by default. What does ‘indented’ mean in this case, and what  do you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: Well, I want to have an parindent in front of the figure caption which works fine. But I don't want to have the same indent for table captions. Here, I want to have no indent and have it completely flushedleft.

Comment: Do you mean at  the left margin of the page or at the left margin of the table?

Comment: I think the left margin of the page. Caption flushedleft, table itself centered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just write:

```
\captionsetup[figure]{labelformat=figure}
```

Comment: Oh, that was dumb -.-